# path format error

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am try to use the following to access a directory on localhost but the error says the path format is not supported.

```
        string fileName=ImageName.ToString() + ".Jpeg";
    bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine("localhost:59657/ProfileTenModified/setP/",  fileName), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

any solutions???

Comment: Would you not need to use `Server.MapPath`..?

Comment: What type of object is "bmp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO operations in .net need absolute paths to the file system. You cannot operate on files or directories with domain names. So as DJ KRAZE said, instead use

```
Server.MapPath("~/ProfileTenModified/setP/" + fileName)
```